# How to write multiple line in a .txt with Python?

Tags: python

I tried this:

```
for a in range(5):
    path_error_folder = r'C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\test'
    if a==3:
        with open(path_error_folder +'/error_report.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write('a\n')
    else:
        with open(path_error_folder +'/error_report.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write('b\n')
```

What I expected:

[image]

What I get:

[image]

Does somebody have an idea why?

Comment: I think what you are looking for; is using `"a"` (append flag) instead of `"w"`, using the write flag just overwrites the file every time you write something to it'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between modes a, a+, w, w+, and r+ in built-in open function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r-in-built-in-open-function)

Comment: Thanks ! It's exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening the file with `'w'` flag you are writing always at the beginning of the file, so after the first write you basically overwrite it each time.

The only character you see is simply the last one you write.

In order to fix it you have two options: either open the file in *append* mode (`'a'`), if you need to preserve your original code structure

```
for a in range(5):
    path_error_folder = r'C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\test'
    if a==3:
        with open(path_error_folder +'/error_report.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write('a\n')
    else:
        with open(path_error_folder +'/error_report.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write('b\n')
```

or, definitely better in order to optimize the process, open the file only once

```
path_error_folder = r'C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\test'
with open(path_error_folder +'/error_report.txt', 'w') as f:
    for a in range(5):
        if a==3:
            f.write('a\n')
        else:
            f.write('b\n')
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your strategy:

```
path_error_folder = r'C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\test'
with open(path_error_folder +'/error_report.txt', 'w') as f:
    for a in range(5):
        if a==3:
            f.write('a\n')
        else:
            f.write('b\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the file with `open(path_error_folder +'/error_report.txt', 'a')`.

Comment: Appending is bad because is it will not empty the file when the program is ran again.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70791797/16001580) is better.

Comment: @BCT Who's to say that's wrong? It might actually be required sometimes...